# How to add our own ML model into Stream.io or Stream Framework

Tags: getstream-io

We are researching Stream.io and Stream Framework.

We want to build a high-volume feed with many producers( sources) that include highly personal messages (private messages?)

For building this feed and to make this relevant for all subcribers  we will need to use our own ML model for the feed personalisation.

We found this as their solution for personalisation but this might scale badly to allow us to run and develop our own ML model 
https://go.getstream.io/knowledge/volumes-and-pricing/can-i

Questions :
1. How do we integrate / add our own ML model for a Getstream-io feed ? 
2. SHould we move more to the Stream Framework and how do we connect our own ML model to that feed solution ?

Thanks for pointing us in the right directions !

Answer (score 0):

we have the ability to work with your team to incorporate ML models into Stream. The model has to be close to the data otherwise lag is an issue. If you use the Stream Framework, you're working with python and your own instance of cassandra, which we stopped using because of performance and scalability issues. If you'd like to discuss options, you can reach out via a form on our site.